# What software is recommended to automate image annotation?

Tags: image-processing, automation, jpeg

We make images like the following in Excel. The raw image is imported and positioned in the generally correct area within the annotations, which are themselves images linked to ranges, the contents of which differ depending on selections made by the user.

The absolute position and dimensions of each annotation must be adjusted manually for every image. The number of sample names can vary (up to 12 lanes of samples). The size ladder on the left can also vary depending on the size of the protein being analyzed.

After everything is correctly sized and aligned, the range containing the raw image + annotations is copied and saved as a jpg (which is then imported into an Access database).

Though we've automated some parts of this with VBA, the process of tweaking every image (widths of columns, text size, position of size ladder, etc.) can get very tedious. Surely there is some software out there that will make this process more efficient. It takes one of our staff members hours to adjust and finalize about 10-20 of these images.

Any recommendations are welcomed.

[image]

This procedure is called electrophoresis. Samples (in this case proteins) are loaded into a polyacrylamide gel (each sample in its own "lane") and pulled through the gel with electricity. This process separates all of the proteins in each lane by size and charge.

The "ladder" is a solution of various proteins of known size. It's used to determine the sizes of the proteins in the other lanes.

The image on the left contains the range of sizes in the ladder (in this case 10, 15,...150, 200). Each "step" in the ladder image is aligned with the black bands that appear in the ladder lane in the experiment (the actual ladder lane that contains the black bands is not present in this case...it's cropped post-alignment to improve the overall look of the image).

The images on the right are protein names and point to the location on the gel where that particular protein should appear. The protein Actin, for example, is supposed to come out at around 42 kilodaltons. The fact that there is a prominent black band in that location is good supporting evidence that this sample contains Actin protein.

Many gels will also describe the sample source at the top or the bottom. So, for example, if the sample in lane 1 was derived from mouse liver cells, lane 1 would be annotated as "mouse liver."

The raw image is captured in the lab and is saved as a jpg. This jpg is then manually copied directly into an Excel sheet, where extraneous parts of the image are cropped. The cropped image is then moved to within the area of the worksheet that contains the annotations (ladder, protein names, sample names). These annotations are themselves images (linked to other ranges in the workbook that change with every experiment...protein names, samples names, ladder type can be different for every experiment). These annotation images require fine positioning in each case (as described previously) to align with the lanes and with the protein sizes. Once everything is aligned, it is saved as a jpg and moved into Access.

My question is...Is there software already out there designed specifically for tasks like these? Just as Excel is not a database program, it is also not an image annotation program. I want to know if there is an application out there, ready to go, that is specifically designed to annotate images with elements that can vary from image to image.

Of course, there will still be a need for manually moving elements around the image to get everything aligned (I'm not looking for a miracle here). I'm thinking that there has to be something better than Excel for this.

Comment: What does the image look like at the start? What's a ladder? What's a lane? Where's a range? How does the info in Excel look?

Comment: I'm sure it would not take too long to write a small python programme which suits your needs. Yet the questions by @MBB70 are crucial in order to get anywhere (they seem technical terms used only in your field of genome analysis(?)).It's especially unclear how the annotations on all three axes relate to the image content. That needs to be clear in an algorithmical sense in order to get anywhere

Comment: You may try the [ImageLines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageLines.html) function in mathematica .. take a trial to make sure.. It's bit of like, killing a fly with a cannon thing.. IMHO, the software is way too big for just this purpose.. you may only need this function anyway.. you may deploy in to the cloud (using cloudDeploy function) if you need flexibility of use. || disclaimer : I'm not promoting this software neither that I'm an agent. I just want to share that thinking ...

Comment: .. along this might help. "If the world don't have it, I'll cr8 one." principle works too. As long as we have a clear algorithm. || I somehow have a habit of using more that one software/tools to get what I need. All in one sometime just didn't work for me..